# Get % of total count while displaying top 10 in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 3 columns date, country, and case numbers. I want to display the top 10 countries with the most cases. I also want to show the % of the grand total. When I select the inbuilt option of show values as %of grand total, it calculates the % based on the filtered out top 10 values. What I need is instead of calculating the % for the top 10 from the 10 records filtered out, it should calculate the % from all the values filtered on the time frame rather than the top 10 which is filtered by cases

I have a big table with more than 100 countries hence I need to show top 10 countries but I need to show the %market each country has of the total. Below is the dummy data.

One more thing to add, my data has the last 5 yrs of data but I'm working on the last 3/6 months rolling window. So the grand total has to be for the last 3/6 months.

[image]

[image: 2]

This is the market share when selected all

[image]

This is the top 10 countries when filtered out by cases

What I need is when I filter out on top 10 countries I get the market share which is calculated when all records are there ie 2nd graph where US is 40%. So basically top 10 countries from 2nd graph but it shouldn't change values when I want to display only top 10 countries and recalculate as it's doing in 3rd image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Using the table you have shared, I have created a calculation that takes the top 2 countries and calculated the `Total Cases` for the last 3 months.

### Total Cases

```
Total Cases =
DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Case Number] )
```

### Calculation 1

The calculation only uses one Table. To force the filter context to be the same for each country I have to use `CALCULATETABLE` on the variable `ListOfDates`.

```
CaseTop10 =
VAR ListOfDates =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DATESINPERIOD (
            'Table'[Created On],
            LASTDATE ( 'Table'[Created On] ),
            -3,
            MONTH
        ),
        ALL ( 'Table' )
    )
VAR TopCountries =
    SUMMARIZE (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            TOPN ( 2, ALL ( 'Table'[Country (Account)] ), [Total Cases], DESC ),
            ListOfDates
        ),
        [Country (Account)]
    )
VAR GTCases =
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE ( [Total Cases], ListOfDates ),
        CALCULATE ( CALCULATE ( [Total Cases], ListOfDates ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Country (Account)] ) IN TopCountries,
        GTCases,
        BLANK ()
    )
```

### Calculation 2

In order to simplify the calculation is better to create a Calendar Table

```
CaseTop10 =
VAR ListOfDates =
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Calendar'[Date], LASTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), -3, MONTH )
VAR TopCountries =
    SUMMARIZE (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            TOPN ( 2, ALL ( 'Table'[Country (Account)] ), [Total Cases], DESC ),
            ListOfDates
        ),
        [Country (Account)]
    )
VAR GTCases =
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE ( [Total Cases], ListOfDates ),
        CALCULATE ( CALCULATE ( [Total Cases], ListOfDates ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Country (Account)] ) IN TopCountries,
        GTCases,
        BLANK ()
    )
```

So, you will need to create a Calendar table, like this

```
Calendar =
CALENDAR ( MIN ( 'Table'[Created On] ), MAX ( 'Table'[Created On] ) )
```

And create a relationship.

[image]

### Output

Either of those two calculations would generate the result on the table on the right.

[image]

Comment: Hi Angelo, I've made an edit to the question, I should've added that before, my bad. So I'm working on the last 3 months of rolling data. Your measure takes the total as we calculate the total sum. I tried myself but I wasn't able to get the last 3 calendar months. could you update it so I get the total of last 3 months.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a full sample dataset? For example, from where your Date column is coming. Also, if you can provide a tabular output of what exactly you want.

Comment: @ShivamSarin Does it solve your question? If it does please mark it as a solution.