# How to create a measure to get % Value in Power BI dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset of countries and cases. I have created a measure to get a distinct count of cases per country. Please refer to the image below. I want the % share of each country. I want to create a measure that gives me a total of the count which is shown below. If I'm able to get the total I can divide this current measure of distinct count by the total count. I don't want to use the option where Power BI shows me the value as %of grand total. I want to manually calculate as a measure.

I'm new to PowerBI and DAX if there is any other better way please let me know. Basically what I need is % share of each country after I take their Distinct Count of cases.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure with a variable that works out the total cases and divides the country quantity by the total cases.  As you do not have numerical count of cases, you'll need to calculate this too

```
Percentage per Country = 
        
    VAR TotalCases = DISTINCTCOUNT( 'CountryCasesText'[CaseRef] )

    VAR PercentageCases = 
        DIVIDE(
            TotalCases , 
            CALCULATE(
                    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'CountryCasesText'[CaseRef] )
                    ,ALL( 'CountryCasesText' )
                )
        )
RETURN
    PercentageCases
```

Then you need to format the column as a percentage.

So starting with the dataset on the left, you can work out the chart on right.
[image: Distinct Count Percentage]

I have added a measure of Case Count for visual reference only, the count is not needed as the calculation is embedded within the Percentage per Country measure

Comment: This doesn't work as my cases column is of type text not numeric. Sumx doesn't work with text type. Hence I was using count not sum. Case column has data in the format of 101-01, etc

Comment: Have revised to cover non numeric case count

Comment: Hey @Daryl, Thanks for this, This almost solves my problem. I have a small issue though, which still remains. The thing is with your query it gives me the global % for the country which is correct. Now If I filter out my records and I need The cases for the last 3 months or 6 months etc. I get the cases filtered out by the date but the total cases still remain the same as we globally declared them to have the case count. Is there any way the total cases can change as per the filter? If I filter records for the last 1 month I need total cases to be updated accordingly and not take the global.

Comment: If you want the percentage to be adjusted based on filters, use AllSelected in place of All inside of the Calculate

Comment: Hi Daryl, Maybe you can help me out on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686255/get-of-total-count-while-displaying-top-10-in-power-bi